# MySQL trigger to send HTTP POST request

Tags: mysql, curl, mariadb

I want to create a trigger in MySQL that sends an HTTP post request to some URL whenever a row is updated/ inserted / deleted in a table. How can I do it?

Comment: http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1497

Answer (score 1):

MySQL, for security reasons, will not send anything outside of its realm -- no emails, no http request, etc.

Have the `TRIGGER` store information about the action into a table for auditing, then have an external program periodically poll that table and take actions.